# "ghandi" is only detected within a string if it is lowercase, doesn't work with any other case

Tags: python, string, list, bots, irc

I'm trying to figure out why this logic is only detecting any lowercase instance of "ghandi" in the string. Ideally, this logic should check the string for the word "ghandi" regardless of case and change the position of h, taking into account its case from the 2nd character to the 5th character. string *msg* should be any string containing "ghandi". This is for an irc bot.

```
  msgList = msg.split()
  for i in range(0, (len(msgList))):
     if 'ghandi' in msgList[i].lower():
        pos = i
        g = list(msgList[i])
        break
     i = i - 1
  if "h" in msgList[pos]:
     h = "h"
  else:
     h = "H"
  del g[1]
  g.insert( 4, h)
  g = ''.join(g)
  del msgList[pos]
  msgList.insert( 5, g )
  msg = ' '.join(msgList)
  cardinal.sendMsg(channel, msg)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are seeing with the code?  It will find ghandi whether it is upper or lowercase. Did you expect it to find multiple words with Ghandi or did you expect it to swap the 'h' regardless of where it is in the word?  This code won't do either of those correctly.  It assumes that Ghandi is at the beginning of the word, that only one word has Ghandi in it, that at least one word has Ghandi in it and that there are at least 6 words in the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it as:

```
msgList = msg.split()
msgList = [i.lower() for i in msgList]
    for i in range(0, (len(msgList))):
        if 'ghandi' in msgList[i]:
            ...
```

Comment: *i* is not defined before this logic and only serves as a variable within the for loop.

Comment: @dragos240, No the two variables are in different scopes, so this will work.

Comment: @dragos240, Was that helpful?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I missed the whole if it being a for loop.

Comment: Not at all. I've figured out the original logic actually worked, but in the bot I had to define what triggers the bot to call a specific function. I set that to accept 'ghandi'. Which means that the function only looks at any lowercase string containing ghandi. I will accept your answer regardless.